# Visual C# Express with DryadLINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Can we use Visual C# Express (instead of Visual Studio) with DryadLINQ?

We know that Visual C# Express 2010 supports LINQ. But I am not sure if DryadLINQ would also be supported, because Dryad might require PLINQ features also.

If anybody can shed light, I would be grateful. Procuring a license for Visual Studio is a tedious process in my organization, and If DryadLINQ can be worked on with Visual C# Express, I can start my work immediately.

Comment: Well this will work 99% no matter of the studio version used.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 1):

For the [beta of Dryad LINQ](https://connect.microsoft.com/HPC/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=35836) (now called LINQ to HPC) we just require that VS can create .NET 3.5 project and link to our client assemblies. While we've not done any testing against the Express VS I don't know of any reason why it wouldn't work.

Ade (PM for LINQ to HPC)